# Array that the elements are tuples, how can I check an index?

Tags: swift

here's an array that the elements are tuples.
And I want to check the elements index by using firstIndex(of:)

```
var f: [(String, String)] = [
    ("a", "a"),
    ("b", "b"),
    ("0", "c"),
    ("d", "d"),
    ("e", "e")
]

var x = f[0]
f.firstIndex(of: x) // error: Type '(String, String)' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
f.firstIndex(of: ("a", "a")) // error: Type '(String, String)' cannot conform to 'Equatable'
```

I tried to find a reason why the error happens, but could not.
Can anybody tell me the reason...?

Searched on google and stack overflow... but couldn't

Comment: `f.firstIndex(where: { $0 == ("b", "b") })` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Equatable conformance for the (String, String) tuple type.

```
extension (String, String): Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: (String, String), rhs: (String, String)) -> Bool {
        return lhs.0 == rhs.0 && lhs.1 == rhs.1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `firstIndex`?

Try using `.0` and `.1`:

```
var f: [(String, String)] = [
    ("a", "a"),
    ("b", "b"),
    ("0", "c"),
    ("d", "d"),
    ("e", "e")
]
var x = f[0]
print(x.0) // prints "a"
print(f[2].0) // prints "0"
print(f[2].1) // prints "c"
```